# Where to apply for Serbian visa in Singapore?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, singapore, embassies, serbia

I am an Indian citizen, residing in Singapore. Since Serbia discontinued the visa on arrival for Indians, I have to apply for visa, if I wish to visit Serbia.

But, there is no embassy for Serbia in Singapore. There is no arrangements with any other embassy like in case of Lithuania (have to apply in Hungarian embassy). When I check the [official website](https://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/foreign-policy/bilateral-cooperation/singapur/embassies-consulates), the nearest embassy is in Indonesia. Does this means that I have to travel to Jakarta, Indonesia and stay there till my visa gets approved and my passport will be returned to me? Is there any other option to get visa to Serbia?

In general, what should I do in similar cases?

*This is a hypothetical question.*

Comment: Can't you travel to Jakarta just for the visa appointment, then get back to Singapore and have the passport mailed back to you? If the visa processing time is just a few days (I don't think Serbia needs to process too many visa applications!), you can of course wait. In that case you can also travel to India, apply for the visa there, and then continue to Serbia...

Comment: @Johnnyjanko I can't go anywhere without my passport. So, mailing back won't work.

Comment: It is not unlikely that you can apply for the visa with a copy of your passport by mail and only have to show up in person at the embassy to get the visa issued. Since the Serbian embassy in Jakarta is responsible for seven other countries in addition to Indonesia, it is probably not too uncommon that people not living in Indonesia apply for a visa there.

Comment: @AnishSheela, oops, you're right. But you can get two passports...